# Uso del vocabolo "pennarello"

Tags: word-usage

Per motivi professionali, ho dovuto leggere gli enunciati di alcuni problemi di matematica per bambini. In uno di questi enunciati ho letto la frase

> Giulio ha nel suo astuccio 18 *pennarelli* ma si accorge che 5 non scrivono più.

La parola *pennarelli* ha attirato la mia attenzione: conoscevo il termine *penna* come strumento per scrivere, ma non *pennarello*. L'ho cercata sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pennarello/) e ho trovato questa definizione

> Nome commerciale di un tipo di penna per disegnare e scrivere, nella quale il pennino è costituito da un pezzetto di feltro a forma di cilindro o di parallelepipedo (per ottenere tratti piuttosto spessi) oppure da una punta di nailon (che dà un segno molto sottile), e pesca in un serbatoio contenente un ammasso fibroso saturo di un inchiostro all’alcol, in varî colori.

In [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/definizione/pennarello) ho trovato persino che si tratta di un marchio commerciale registrato.

La mia domanda è sull'uso che se fa nel linguaggio comune di questo vocabolo: si adopera veramente come un marchio commerciale o se ne fa un uso più ampio?

Se si tratta di un marchio registrato, lo stesso oggetto fabbricato da un altro marchio viene anche chiamato commercialmente "pennarello"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

È un termine comunissimo, a prescindere dalla sua origine, usato anche dai bambini a scuola (o anzi, fuori scuola, perché a scuola sono preferite le matite colorate).

Linguisticamente, è un esempio di *volgarizzazione*, in cui un termine nato come marchio registrato entra poi nell'uso comune, tanto che a volte non si ha neppure presente la sua origine commerciale: “candeggina”, “borotalco” etc. C'è qualche esempio in [questo articolo](http://blog.terminologiaetc.it/2015/05/07/volgarizzazione-marchi/), tra cui appunto “pennarello”.

Come mostra la foto che segue, di confezioni di due marche diverse, il termine è tanto entrato nell'uso (e presumibilmente non più protetto) che viene usato anche dai produttori.

[image]

Comment: Capisco, ma nelle scatole di questo tipo di penna c'è scritto "pennarelli"?

Comment: Giusta domanda: ho aggiornato la risposta.

Comment: A scuola si preferiscono le matite colorate? Quando andavo all'asilo (~'84-'86) usavamo solo i pennarelli (oltre ai colori a dita) – non ricordo se alle Elementari ci facevano disegnare o meno, ma ricordo abbastanza chiaramente di non aver usato quasi mai le matite…

Comment: Ma siamo proprio sicuri che pennarello era un marchio registrato? Possibile che non si riesca a trovare una fonte più autorevole?

Comment: @WalterTross: Il Treccani in genere è considerato abbastanza autorevole. Comunque lo confermano anche il Devoto-Oli (di carta) e il DOP di Migliorini-Tagliavini-Fiorelli (di carta). Comunque, pqcv, in effetti anch'io non lo avverto come volgarizzazione, a differenza di altre più recenti come “bic” o “scottex”.

Comment: Aggiungo un [articolo sulla *Repubblica* di 20 anni fa](http://ricerca.repubblica.it/repubblica/archivio/repubblica/1995/05/24/attenzione-parole-rischio.html), in cui “pennarello” è addirittura citato come termine che non si poteva usare come denominazione generica, e un [articolo di Vittorio Coletti](http://www.publifarum.farum.it/ezine_articles.php?art_id=162) in cui “pennarello” appare come esempio di marchionimo.

Comment: _Nome commerciale_ e _marchionimo_ sono cose diverse, e lo conferma anche l'articolo di Coletti, che però su _pennarello_ mi pare fare un po' di confusione. La mia domanda era: siamo proprio sicuri che _pennarello_ era un _marchio registrato_, ovvero, un _marchionimo_? Non riesco a prima lettura a trovare la risposta nell'articolo di Coletti, mentre, SE è vero quello che dice l'articolo di Repubblica, allora è confermato che _pennarello_ era un marchionimo. Peraltro non è possibile registrare come marchi termini semplicemente derivabili dalla lingua italiana, e _pennarello_ è un po' al limite.

Comment: @WalterTross: Sono un po' confuso: puoi chiarire meglio la distinzione? Il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/marchionimo/) definisce “marchionimo” testualmente «In linguistica, nome con cui è noto in commercio un determinato prodotto o il nome dell’azienda che lo produce; nome commerciale».

Comment: Mi correggo: nel mio commento precedente _marchionimo_ va sostituito ovunque con _marchio registrato_. Ad una prima lettura dell'articolo di Coletti, avendo lì incontrato per la prima volta il termine _marchionimo_ (assente in molti dizionarî), l'ho preso per sinomino di _marchio registrato_ (non so cosa mi abbia indotto in errore). Ad ogni modo il punto rimane lo stesso: un _nome commerciale_ non è necessariamente un _marchio registrato_. P.es., _musicassetta_ non è mai stato un marchio registrato, quindi il suo uso è sempre stato libero. Ho il sospetto che valga altrettanto per _pennarello_.

Comment: @WalterTross: Rispondendo alla domanda su “marca” e “marchio” mi accorgo che la voce [“Nomi commerciali”](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/nomi-commerciali_(Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano)/) dell'*Enciclopedia dell'italiano* pone esplicitamente “pennarello” (e “musicassetta”) tra gli esempi di marchionimi che sono marchi registrati: «bikini, braille, candeggina, cornetto «gelato», cremino, fòrmica, frigidaire, gommapiuma, mangianastri, musicassetta, pennarello, ping-pong, piumone, salvavita «interruttore automatico», scolorina, sottiletta «tipo di formaggio», termocoperta, thermos, zip, ecc.»

Comment: Peccato, su _musicassetta_ avevo "spremuto" Google - ma, a quanto pare, non abbastanza... Purtroppo la banca dati dell'[Ufficio Italiano Brevetti e Marchi](http://www.uibm.gov.it/) è interrogabile solo a partire dal 1980. Noto comunque, nell'articolo da te citato, che c'è _anche_ chi identifica _marchionimo_ con _marchio brevettato_, anche se a me risulta che un marchio non si _brevetta_, bensì si _registra_. Mi pare che linguisti e legali non si parlino molto...