# Differenze di uso tra "marchio" e "marca" per un nome commerciale

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

Quando ho scritto il testo di [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/5601/707) ho usato il termine "marchio", ma ho osservato che @DaG ha usato "marca" nella sua risposta. Non riesco a capire quale sia la differenza di uso tra questi due vocaboli quando si tratta del nome commerciale di un prodotto o del nome della dita che lo produce. Potreste spiegarmelo?

Per aumentare di più la mia confusione, nei commenti alla risposta di @DaG, è stato introdotto un terzo vocabolo per esprimere questo tipo di concetto: "marchionimo".

Answer (score 4):

Dal Treccani [Marchio](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/marchio/) e [Marca](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/marca1/) sembrano entrambi essere, in ultima istanza, termini di origine germanica che hanno il significato originario di "segno".

Entrambi possono essere usati in modo intercambiabile **nel contesto di ditta produttrice**. I termini hanno anche altri significati, come *marca da bollo* per indicare una certa tassa da applicare ai documenti, per cui i due termini non sono intercambiabili. *Marca* viene usato specificatamente per molte espressioni simili a *marca da bollo*, come *marca della zecca* o *marca tipografica*.

Esiste anche un'espressione particolare: *di marca*, usata per indicare un prodotto di una marca prestigiosa, per cui non si può usare il termine *marchio*.

Se vogliamo essere pignoli la differenza d'uso tra i due termini, in questo contesto, è che solitamente *marca* indica genericamente la ditta produttrice, *marchio* viene usato più per indicare il segno stesso usato per rappresentare la marca. Ad esempio, marca: Ferrari, marchio: [logo della Ferrari](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrari#/media/File:Logo_della_Ferrari_S.p.A..svg).

Onestamente marchionimo non lo avevo mai sentito, dalla [voce sul Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/marchionimo/) indica il nome di un prodotto di una specifica marca che è in uso per indicare tutti i prodotti di quel tipo. Non mi vengono in mente esempi in italiano, ma gli americani usano *to google* per intendere "usare un motore di ricerca".

Comment: È un fenomeno diffusissimo anche in italiano; qualche esempio lo trovi nelle risposte e nei commenti alla domanda citata dall'OP, e altri ne trovi nella voce [“Nomi commerciali”](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/nomi-commerciali_(Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano)/) dell'*Enciclopedia dell'italiano*: «bikini, braille, candeggina, cornetto «gelato», cremino, fòrmica, frigidaire, gommapiuma, mangianastri, musicassetta, pennarello, ping-pong, piumone, salvavita «interruttore automatico», scolorina, sottiletta «tipo di formaggio», termocoperta, thermos, zip, ecc.»

Answer (score 2):

"[Marketing Freaks](http://www.themarketingfreaks.com/2014/03/logo-marca-e-marchio-simili-ma-non-troppo/)" traccia un'interessante distinzione tra i due termini.

Il Marchio:

> - Quando parliamo di ***marchio*** alcuni lo intendono come logotipo, definendolo come equivalente a quest'ultimo. È più corretto però sottolineare, a livello di marketing, la differenza sostanziale: ***il marchio è la denominazione statica, il simbolo distintivo che ha la principale funzione di far riconoscere e differenziare l’azienda, è anche definito come trademark***.  Tutto ciò implica ovviamente il diritto ad utilizzare certi colori e certi grafie e permette di proteggere la proprietà intellettuale legalmente.
> - Possono essere registrati come marchi:
>
>   - Parole,
>   - Nomi,
>   - Disegni,
>   - Lettere,
>   - Cifre,
>   - Suoni,
>   - Forma di un prodotto,
>   - Packaging,
>   - Combinazioni cromatiche.
> - Fondamentalmente si suddividono in tre macrocategorie:
>
>   - ***Marchio figurativo*** (una o più parole in una determinata grafia/disegno)
>   - ***Marchio verbale*** (una o più dicitura costituita da grafia normale)
>   - ***Altre tipologie*** (3D, sonoro, olfattivo…)

La Marca:

> - ***La marca*** è un elemento complesso e molto più intangibile, ***riguarda soprattutto il valore che l’azienda è capace di trasmettere al cliente  ed è legata al posizionamento nella mente di quest’ultimo o meglio, si crea proprio nella sua mente.***
> - La marca comprende la storia aziendale, l’insieme dei prodotti /servizi di tutti gli elementi facenti parti dell’azienda e che permettono di renderla più o meno unica e differenziarla dalla concorrenza, si tratta di un elemento dinamico. Non si limita però solamente agli aspetti interni all’attività ma anzi il maggior peso è dovuto all’awareness, all’opinione degli stakeholders e dei clienti, alle aspettative, ai valori.
> - In questo senso Kotler suddivide così le dimensioni a cui appartengono i significati della marca:
>
>   - Attributi,
>   - Benefici,
>   - Valori,
>   - Cultura,
>   - Personalità.

Nel linguaggio comune *marca* viene usato per riferirsi al *brand* di un prodotto, mentre il termine corretto sarebbe *marchio*.

- Di che marca sono le tue scarpe?